# iOS ARC UIAlertView leaking memory

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, uialertview, instruments

I have simple method showing AlertView with textfield. Instruments showing memory leak in this. Please explain.

```
- (void)method {
NSString *value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"key"];
if (value == nil) {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    alertView.tag = 101;
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    UITextField *txtGroup = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    [txtGroup becomeFirstResponder];

    [alertView show];
    alertView = nil;
}
}
```

Please find the screenshot of Instruments:
[image]

Comment: Why are you making alertView = nil ? after showing?

Comment: I read somewhere, to release an object it need to set to nil after use.

Comment: From here, http://blog.harbinger-systems.com/2014/04/ios-memory-management-and-arc/

Comment: Yes. Agree but when you are showing alert view means still it's in the hierarchy and you are making it to nil immediately. In ARC it will take care of it. If you want to do it, do it after usage

Comment: how to remove it from hierarchy and release(dealloc) it? when?

Comment: no need of this `alertView = nil;

Comment: Did you dismiss the alertview?

Comment: when to dismiss? It will get dismiss on click of OK button, right?

Comment: why there is leak, I want to know ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create alertView as :

```
static UIAlertView *alertView = nil;

if (!alertView){
   alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
}
```

Comment: why should UIAlertView as static?

Comment: because when you call this method then alertview create new instance so.

Comment: you can declared global alertiview instead of static .

Comment: why there is leak, I want to know ? And, how to remove it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143478/discussion-between-kkrocks-and-pk86).